# At least one of these numbers are irrational: $a$ or $\ln a$.

Tags: irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

I've found a proof that:
$(1)$ if $a\neq1$ is a positive real number than at least one of these numbers are irrational: $a$ or $\ln a$.

I was told that this result is a corollary of Lindemann theorem, that states that if $b$ is algebraic than $e^b$ is transcedental. How does Lindemann theorem implies $(1)?$

I've found $(1)$ to be interesting because if we set $a=e\pi$, than at least one is irrational: $e\pi$ or $\ln \pi$.

Comment: Well...if $\ln a$ is algebraic then $\exp (\ln a)$ is transcendental.  (unless $a=1$ of course).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need more than $e$ is transcedental. Let $b=\ln a$, and if both of $a,b$ are rational, then $e^b=a$ is rational, and hence $e=a^{1/b}$ is algebraic: If $b=\frac{m}{n}, m,n\in\mathbb Z$, then $e^{m}=a^{n}\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: But $(1)$ states that $a$ is a real number not just rational or algebraic...

Comment: I showed $a$ and $\ln(a)$ cannot be both rational, hence at least one of them is irrational.